# filter timedate column in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and am stuck with a timedate column in R. 
I have a data which have multiple columns and one the column has date and time like

```
Originaltime               magnitude     depth
2017-01-10T16:42:23.247Z   4.6            18.8
1963-09-02T23:16:55.510Z   3.767          12
1963-08-29T16:46:25.520Z   3.727          12
```

I want to filter my data using `originaltime` column, but use only year for my filter.

I have tried:

```
b <- year(historiceventstbl$origintime)
head(b)
#[1] 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017
```

I am not sure, how to go from here.

Comment: `historiceventstbl[year(historiceventstbl$origintime)==2017,]` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
      filter(year(Originaltime)==1963)
#                Originaltime magnitude depth
#1 1963-09-02T23:16:55.510Z     3.767    12
#2 1963-08-29T16:46:25.520Z     3.727    12
```

---

Or using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, year(Originaltime)==1963)
```

---

Or with using only `base R`

```
subset(df1, sub("^(.{4}).*", "\\1", Originaltime)==1963)
#              Originaltime magnitude depth
#2 1963-09-02T23:16:55.510Z     3.767    12
#3 1963-08-29T16:46:25.520Z     3.727    12
```

It may be better to use Date time functions when manipulating time, so

```
subset(df1, format(as.POSIXct(Originaltime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS"), "%Y") == 1963)
#             Originaltime magnitude depth
#2 1963-09-02T23:16:55.510Z     3.767    12
#3 1963-08-29T16:46:25.520Z     3.727    12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this with your data with `base R` only:

```
df[substring(as.character(df$Originaltime), 1, 4) == 2017,]
#              Originaltime magnitude depth
#1 2017-01-10T16:42:23.247Z       4.6  18.8
```